# Loading models not available in keras.applications?

Tags: keras

I want to import model AlexNet but module keras.application doesn't have AlexNet. [Available models in keras](https://keras.io/applications/).

Answer (score 1):

You can write it yourself - specify model as described in paper, and then load weights into the model.  See implementation of [VGG16](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/vgg16.py), and other models in [source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/tree/master/keras/applications) as an example.